# How to create Priority Queue that sorts based on certain attribute of class?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have created a Node class:

```
public class Node {
int vertex;
double latency;
Node predecessor;}

 public double getLatency()
{
    return latency;
}
```

I want to create a Priority Queue that sorts the Nodes by latency from least to greatest. After research, I believe I need to override the Comparator?

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pqueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(numVertices, new Comparator<Node>({
        @Override

            ???
        }
    }
```

I'm not too sure how to override it.

Comment: 2 minutes of google would've given you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "???" in your example can be replaced with the following:

```
public int compare(Node a, Node b) {
    if (a.getLatency() < b.getLatency())
        return -1;
    else if (a.getLatency() > b.getLatency())
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just actually need to compare both latencies. That means overriding the method `compare` of the class Comparator comparing the latency of both input `Node`:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pqueue = new PriorityQueue<Node>(numVertices, new Comparator<Node>({
    @Override
    public int compare(Node a, Node b) {
        return Integer.compare(a.getLatency(), b.getLatency());
    }
}
```

However this only works for Java 7, for other versions:

```
new Integer(a.getLatency()).compareTo(new Integer(b.getLatency()));
```

If you don't want to create a new Object then compare both `int` as usual